# Change vim syntax highlighting for html files

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting, macvim

Currently when I use vim to edit hmtl files, all the header tags are greyed out and in bold. How do I make it white and normal font-weight when like the paragraph tag?

I use Vundle to install the plugins and I use

```
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
```

and Tomorrow-Night-Eighties as the colorscheme.

Here is how it looks:
[vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCdvZ.png)

Comment: That color and style is defined by your colorscheme. Edit it.

Comment: Hey, I don't think the change in font-weight or color is due to the color scheme. It would be some other plugin.